# Removing highlighting when selecting feature in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, attribute-table, query

Whenever I select a feature in an attribute table it gets highlighted which prevents me from seeing the symbology of that feature. I tried choosing No Color in the appearance option, but that results in it being highlighted white.

This is what it looks like after a select by attribute query (how I'd like it)
[image]

But this is how it appears when I double click the feature to go to it
[image]

Anyone know a way to make it hollow or adjust the transparency?

Comment: Please post what version of ArcMap you are using.  I can't replicate this error in 10.2 so I'm guessing you have an older version.

Comment: @SaraBarnes I am using 10.1. I found that when right clicking and selecting Pan To the issues goes away.

Comment: I'm glad you have a workaround.  I don't understand why you'd still be having this error.  It could be a glitch in 10.1.  In 10.2 it works correctly when I double click.

Comment: Is your attribute table in "show selected records" mode, instead of "show all records"?

Comment: I do not recall ever seeing selection display behaviour like you describe at any release of ArcGIS for Desktop (8.0 - 10.2).  Does it still behave like this after 1. a restart of ArcMap, 2. a reboot of your PC/laptop, and 3. deleting/renaming your Normal.mxt to restore ArcMap's factory settings?

Comment: You are in Selected Records Only mode in a Table View.  Highlighted records are always opaque (No Color is white, not transparent). Solutions after highlighting: Toggle between Show Selected Records mode and Show All Records mode to show or hide highlighting without removing highlighting.  To remove highlighting click far left of one record to switch from group highlighting to single record, then hold the Ctrl key and click far left side of that record to remove highlighting from the last record. Solutions without highlighting: Right click the far left of a record and choose Pan To or Zoom To.

Comment: Please vote for my idea on the ESRI ideas website to improve record highlighting behaviors in the table view.  https://c.na9.visual.force.com/apex/ideaView?id=087E00000005Ajh&mc=0

Comment: @PolyGeo I attempted all of those solutions and the issue persists. It seems like it only occurs in the "Selected Records Only" view that Richard posted.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst It looks like there is plenty in your comment to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in Selected Records Only mode in a Table View. Highlighted records are always opaque (No Color is white, not transparent). Solutions after highlighting: Toggle between Show Selected Records mode and Show All Records mode to show or hide highlighting without removing highlighting. To remove highlighting click far left of one record to switch from group highlighting to single record, then hold the Ctrl key and click far left side of that record to remove highlighting from the last record. Solutions without highlighting: Right click the far left of a record and choose Pan To or Zoom To.